# Extract values from complex JSON

Tags: javascript, json, csv

I have a large and complex JSON and I want to extract specific values to a csv file

I created the Javascript function to convert the JSON to CSV.
I don't know how to extract the values.

Comment: Are you trying to get all the questions in recordCollection.record ?

Comment: from ex:SCR5ra   until   ex:SS8NC__Implementation_Comments

Comment: Where do `Implementation` and `Implementation comment` come from?

Comment: SCR5ra until SS8NC are questions of a questionnaire. Each question has an Answer, Answer Comment, Implementation and  Implementation Comment. If the question in the  JSON has not value for the fields then I place "" empty value

Comment: Almost completed it, will post the solution when done.

Comment: Finished the solution. You can find it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution. We import the json file, then search through the record for keys that include "answer_comments", since all the questions have that key.

Then we take the name of title of the questions using regex.

Now that we have the title of the questions, we can loop through them and get the values for each.

```
const data = require("./data.json");
const record = data["ex:recordCollection"]["ex:record"];

const questions = Object.keys(record).filter((a) =>
  a.toLowerCase().includes("answer_comments")
);

const result = questions.map((q) => {
  const title: string = q.match(/(?<=ex:)(.*)(?=__)/gm)[0];

  return {
    question: title,
    answer: record[`ex:${title}`]["ex:Item"]["_text"],
    answer_comment: !record[`ex:${title}__Answer_Comments`] && "",
    implementation: record[`ex:${title}__Implementation`]
      ? record[`ex:${title}__Implementation`]["ex:Item"]["_text"]
      : "",
    implementation_comments:
      !record[`ex:${title}__Implementation_Comments`] && "",
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @ada here's the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I run your code and I get the error "SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration" when you declare const title: string = q.match(/(?<=ex:)(.*)(?=__)/gm)[0];  Do I have to include any extra package in package.json?

Comment: If you are using vanilla JS, remove the `: string` part in the line the error appears. That's a Typescript type annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Object.Keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) if interested in keys, [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) for the values associated with those keys and [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) if you want both of them.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse` is the function you are looking for. It parses JSON data and converts it into a native javascript object. You could fetch the file, and pass it to the function

Example:

```
const fs = require("fs") 
var json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('/path/to/file.json', 'utf8'));
```

You can also simply require a json file like this:

```
const json = require("path/to/file.json")
```

However, I do not recommend this approach as there are many drawbacks:

1. `require` is blocking, which means if you load large json files, it will block excution until it finishes loading
2. The file is only read once, and subsequent calls will only return cached verions